# Adding two dollars amount in JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

My goal is make a variable called

```
"Dollar Diff" = Value of posting.dollarsInHeader -posting.dollarsReceived)/1000000
```

Check code below

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${posting.dollarsInHeader != 0 || posting.dollarsReceived != 0}">
        <td class="alignright" class="${posting.dollarsInHeader < 0 || posting.dollarsReceived < 0 ? 'fontRed' : ''}">
            <fmt:formatNumber type="currency" minFractionDigits="1"
                                            maxFractionDigits="1">${(posting.dollarsInHeader - posting.dollarsReceived)/1000000}
        </td>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 10px;">-</td>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Instead of `${(posting.dollarsInHeader - posting.dollarsReceived)/1000000}`, I want to write `${dollarDiff}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend such logic written in view layer (jsp). 
You can add a field in your posting class and write return the value accordingly.

```
//Ommit Posting class declaration
public double getDollarDiff(){
    return (this.dollarsInHeader-this.dollarsReceived)/1000000;
}
```

Then simply reference it with:

```
${posting.dollarDiff}
```

EL treat your method as a field if it follow getter convention.

However, if you don't want to modify your pojo, you could try use

```
<c:set scope="request" var="dollarDiff" value="${(posting.dollarsInHeader - posting.dollarsReceived)/1000000}"></c:set>
```

Then reference it with:

```
<c:out value="${requestScope.dollarDiff}"></c:out> 
<!--or-->
${requestScope.dollarDiff}
```